# VS Code Keeps Generating Pycache Files

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-code, pyc

I already added the following snippet to the top of my python codes to prevent pycache files from being generated.

```
import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True
```

Now, if I run the files (unit tests) individually, no pycache file is generated. However, as soon as I use the Testing feature of VS Code to run all unit tests one after another, it consistently generates a **pycache** folder.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: python generates bytecodes of the imported python modules. This question may not be related to VSCode

Comment: What actually happens when you run your tests with VSCode is it doesn't run the same command you are typing in the terminal to run your tests individually, I'd point out that it might be what is causing your pycache folders to be generated. Note when you run it through the interface it will emit a 'command' with quite a few parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reasons for Pycache folder generation**

When B.py import A.py, there will generate a A.pyc

**How to avoid .pyc files**

1. `python3 -B test.py`  Use this command run the .py file.
2. add the following code into the .py file:

import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True

3. Setting environment variables

   PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

[image]

According to your situation, I suggest you tring the third way to avoid the .pyc file.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding on here in case this helps anyone, make sure you place the assignment to `sys.dont_write_bytecode` above any other (non builtin) imports, or those imports might incur caching.